# Get a specific nested JSON property using JObject

Tags: c#, json, json.net

How do I get a specific nested property from a JSON using JObject?

For example i want to get the uri:

```
{
"embed": {
    "uri": "/presets/88930"
```

...

Comment: `myJObj["embed"]["uri"]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's many ways to access the property you're interested in.

Here's one:

```
    String jsonData = "{ 'embed': { 'uri': '/presets/88930'}}";
    var jObject = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(jsonData);
    Console.WriteLine((string)jObject["embed"]["uri"]);
```

Comment: how can we make it exception free. In case if no uri property is there with json , then how we can write this

Answer (score 3):

if your jObject looks like:

```
var j = JObject.Parse(@"{""embed"": { ""uri"": ""/presets/88930"" } }");
```

dynamics makes accessing the object pretty easy:

```
string value = ((dynamic)j).embed.uri.ToString();
```